# I have a code that detects if the sentence inputted is a Palindrome or not. But I want to make it so uppercases and lower cases dont mattter

Tags: python

```
string = (input("Enter your own string: "))
if string == string[::-1]:
  print("This is a Palindrome")
else:
  print("This is not a Palindrome")
```

I want this code to not care about lower or upper case please

Comment: Then just make it lower case every time -> `if string.lower() == string[::-1].lower()`

Comment: Learn about built in string functions here in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower

Comment: FYI If you searched just a little bit for relevant keywords like in this case _python string lower case_ you would find loads of helpful results without having to ask a question here. And then you wouldn’t risk downvotes and close votes for questions which you could answer yourself with minimal research :-)

Answer (score 0):

First either convert the string to all lower or upper characters like this;

```
new_str = string.lower()
if new_str == new_str[::-1]:
   ...rest of your code here
```

Comment: Downvote for not testing?

Comment: My bad for the typo. Resolved now